# mutable method X.this is not callable using a immutable object error in D

Tags: class, d

I have this D code copied from this page: http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/class.html

```
import std.stdio;

struct S {
    this (int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    int x;
}

class Foo
{
    S      o;  
    char[] s;
    int    i;

// ...

    this(S o, const char[] s, int i)
    {
        this.o = o;
        this.s = s.dup;
        this.i = i;
    }

    Foo dup() const
    {
        return new Foo(o, s, i);
    }

    immutable(Foo) idup() const
    {
        return new immutable(Foo)(this.o, this.s, this.i);
    }
}

void main()
{
    auto var1 = new Foo(S(5), "hello", 42);
    auto var2 = var1.dup();
    immutable(Foo) imm = var1.idup();

    writeln(var1);
    writeln(var2);
    writeln(imm);
}
```

The issue is that I have "mutable method a.Foo.this is not callable using a immutable object" error when compile it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're receiving this error because you called `new immutable(Foo)(this.o, this.s, this.i);` This looks for a an `immutable` constructor, and you only have a constructor for a mutable object defined, which is the default. You can solve this by writing a constructor and marking it `immutable`, much like how you mark methods as `const`, but there is better and often easier solution.

Try marking your constructors and methods as `pure` if you can. If you mark the constructor as `pure`, then the constructor can be used for both mutable and `immutable` objects. Alternatively, you can mark your `idup` method as `pure`, construct a `new Foo`, which is a mutable object, and return it as `immutable`. This is all because `pure` functions can safely create immutable data if the data returned isn't referenced elsewhere. In other words, uniquely owned memory can be moved out into `immutable` types.